# Magento Generate csv when a customer is registered

Tags: magento-1.7

is it possible to  generate a csv file with customer details when a customer is registered in magento website?is there any functionality default in magento?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no default functionality for this. 
You can create an observer for event `customer_register_success` and in this observer you can write your custom code to generate a csv file.